# Moved from TexLive 2018 to 2020 and now I'm getting countless font errors

Tags: fonts, errors, texlive-2020

After sticking with TexLive 2018 for over two years, I decided to move on to TexLive 2020. I followed the instruction [here](https://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html), changed my path to point to the new TexLive directory, rebooted and so on. I ran `sudo fc-cache -fv`. I attempted to update the install through `tlmgr`, just in case, but I already had every single package installed and updated (except four that have "Windows" in their names).

In spite of all of the above, now when I try and use TexLive 2020 to compile documents that were working yesterday with TexLive 2018, I get uncountable errors, mostly related with fonts.

`missfont.log` shows only missing fonts:

```
mktextfm LatinModernMath-Regular/OT
mktextfm LatinModernMath-Regular/OT
mktextfm LatinModernMath-Regular/OT
mktextfm LatinModernMath-Regular/B/OT
mktextfm LatinModernMath-Regular/OT
mktextfm LatinModernMath-Regular/OT
mktextfm LatinModernMath-Regular/OT
mktextfm LatinModernMath-Regular/OT
mktextfm LatinModernMath-Regular/OT
mktextfm LatinModernMath-Regular/OT
mktextfm LatinModernMath-Regular/B/OT
mktextfm LatinModernMath-Regular/OT
mktextfm LatinModernMath-Regular/OT
mktextfm LatinModernMath-Regular/OT
mktextfm LatinModernMath-Regular/OT
mktextfm LatinModernMath-Regular/OT
mktextfm LatinModernMath-Regular/OT
mktextfm LatinModernMath-Regular/OT
mktextfm LatinModernMath-Regular/OT
mktextfm LatinModernMath-Regular/OT
mktextfm LatinModernMath-Regular/OT
mktextfm LatinModernMath-Regular/B/OT
mktextfm LatinModernMath-Regular/OT
mktextfm LatinModernMath-Regular/OT
mktextfm LatinModernMath-Regular/OT
mktextfm LatinModernMath-Regular/OT
mktextfm LatinModernMath-Regular/OT
mktextfm LatinModernMath-Regular/OT
mktextfm LatinModernMath-Regular/B/OT
mktextfm LatinModernMath-Regular/OT
mktextfm LatinModernMath-Regular/OT
mktextfm LatinModernMath-Regular/OT
mktextfm LatinModernMath-Regular/OT
mktextfm LatinModernMath-Regular/OT
mktextfm LatinModernMath-Regular/OT
mktextfm LatinModernMath-Regular/OT
```

The document's compilation log has many more problems. It's 1 MB+, so I'm including some highlights here.

In spite of not appearing in `missfont.log`, there are these errors:

```
! Package fontspec Error: The font "Linux Libertine O" cannot be found.
! Package fontspec Error: The font "Linux Biolinum O Bold" cannot be found.
! Package fontspec Error: The font "Libertinus Sans" cannot be found.
! Package fontspec Error: The font "LatinModernMath-Regular" cannot be found.
```

A more detailed version of one of those error messages is here:

```
! Package fontspec Error: The font "Linux Libertine O" cannot be found.

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.1235 
       

A font might not be found for many reasons.
 Check the spelling, where the font is installed etc. etc.

 When in doubt, ask someone for help!



Package fontspec Info: Could not resolve font "Linux Libertine O/BI" (it
(fontspec)             probably doesn't exist).


Package fontspec Info: Could not resolve font "Linux Libertine O/B" (it
(fontspec)             probably doesn't exist).


Package fontspec Info: Could not resolve font "Linux Libertine O/I" (it
(fontspec)             probably doesn't exist).


! Package fontspec Error: The font "Linux Libertine O" cannot be found.

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.1235 
       

A font might not be found for many reasons.
 Check the spelling, where the font is installed etc. etc.

 When in doubt, ask someone for help!



! Package fontspec Error: The font "Linux Libertine O" cannot be found.

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.1235 
       

A font might not be found for many reasons.
 Check the spelling, where the font is installed etc. etc.

 When in doubt, ask someone for help!



Package fontspec Info: Font family 'LinuxLibertineO(1)' created for font
(fontspec)             'Linux Libertine O' with options
(fontspec)             [Ligatures=TeX,Ligatures=TeX,Mapping=tex-text].
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)              This font family consists of the following NFSS
(fontspec)             series/shapes:
(fontspec)              
(fontspec)             - 'normal' (m/n) with NFSS spec.: <->"Linux Libertine
(fontspec)             O"
(fontspec)             - 'small caps'  (m/sc) with NFSS spec.: <->"Linux
(fontspec)             Libertine O"


! Package fontspec Error: The font "Linux Libertine O" cannot be found.

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.1235 
       

A font might not be found for many reasons.
 Check the spelling, where the font is installed etc. etc.

 When in doubt, ask someone for help!



Package fontspec Info: Could not resolve font "Linux Libertine O/BI" (it
(fontspec)             probably doesn't exist).


Package fontspec Info: Could not resolve font "Linux Libertine O/B" (it
(fontspec)             probably doesn't exist).


Package fontspec Info: Could not resolve font "Linux Libertine O/I" (it
(fontspec)             probably doesn't exist).
```

I *do* have have this font on my system. In my TexLive directory tree. In fact, there are over 5300 files relating to it. Here is a small sample, cut down due to the SX character limit:

```
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/libertine
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/libertine/LinBiolinum_K.otf
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/libertine/LinBiolinum_R.otf
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/libertine/LinBiolinum_RB.otf
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/libertine/LinBiolinum_RBO.otf
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/libertine/LinBiolinum_RI.otf
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/libertine/LinLibertine_DR.otf
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/libertine/LinLibertine_I.otf
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/libertine/LinLibertine_M.otf
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/libertine/LinLibertine_MB.otf
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/libertine/LinLibertine_MBO.otf
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/libertine/LinLibertine_MO.otf
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/libertine/LinLibertine_R.otf
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/libertine/LinLibertine_RB.otf
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/libertine/LinLibertine_RBI.otf
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/libertine/LinLibertine_RI.otf
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/libertine/LinLibertine_RZ.otf
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/libertine/LinLibertine_RZI.otf
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumO-lf-ly1--base.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumO-lf-ly1.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumO-lf-ot1--base.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumO-lf-ot1.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumO-lf-sc-ly1--base.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumO-lf-sc-ly1.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumO-lf-sc-ot1--base.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumO-lf-sc-ot1.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumO-lf-sc-t1--base.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumO-lf-sc-t1.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumO-lf-t1--base.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumO-lf-t1.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumO-lf-ts1--base.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumO-lf-ts1.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumO-osf-ly1--base.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumO-osf-ly1.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumO-osf-ot1--base.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumO-osf-ot1.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumO-osf-sc-ly1--base.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumO-osf-sc-ly1.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumO-osf-sc-ot1--base.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumO-osf-sc-ot1.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumO-osf-sc-t1--base.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumO-osf-sc-t1.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumO-osf-t1--base.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumO-osf-t1.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumO-osf-ts1--base.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumO-osf-ts1.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumO-tlf-ly1--base.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumO-tlf-ly1.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumO-tlf-ot1--base.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumO-tlf-ot1.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumO-tlf-sc-ly1--base.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumO-tlf-sc-ly1.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumO-tlf-sc-ot1--base.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumO-tlf-sc-ot1.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumO-tlf-sc-t1--base.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumO-tlf-sc-t1.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumO-tlf-t1--base.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumO-tlf-t1.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumO-tlf-ts1--base.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumO-tlf-ts1.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumO-tosf-ly1--base.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumO-tosf-ly1.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumO-tosf-ot1--base.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumO-tosf-ot1.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumO-tosf-sc-ly1--base.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumO-tosf-sc-ly1.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumO-tosf-sc-ot1--base.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumO-tosf-sc-ot1.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumO-tosf-sc-t1--base.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumO-tosf-sc-t1.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumO-tosf-t1--base.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumO-tosf-t1.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumO-tosf-ts1--base.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumO-tosf-ts1.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumOB-lf-ly1--base.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumOB-lf-ly1.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumOB-lf-ot1--base.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumOB-lf-ot1.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumOB-lf-sc-ly1--base.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumOB-lf-sc-ly1.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumOB-lf-sc-ot1--base.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumOB-lf-sc-ot1.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumOB-lf-sc-t1--base.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumOB-lf-sc-t1.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumOB-lf-t1--base.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumOB-lf-t1.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumOB-lf-ts1--base.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumOB-lf-ts1.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumOB-osf-ly1--base.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumOB-osf-ly1.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumOB-osf-ot1--base.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumOB-osf-ot1.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumOB-osf-sc-ly1--base.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumOB-osf-sc-ly1.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumOB-osf-sc-ot1--base.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumOB-osf-sc-ot1.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumOB-osf-sc-t1--base.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumOB-osf-sc-t1.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumOB-osf-t1--base.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumOB-osf-t1.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumOB-osf-ts1--base.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumOB-osf-ts1.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumOB-tlf-ly1--base.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumOB-tlf-ly1.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumOB-tlf-ot1--base.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumOB-tlf-ot1.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumOB-tlf-sc-ly1--base.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumOB-tlf-sc-ly1.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumOB-tlf-sc-ot1--base.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumOB-tlf-sc-ot1.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumOB-tlf-sc-t1--base.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumOB-tlf-sc-t1.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumOB-tlf-t1--base.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumOB-tlf-t1.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumOB-tlf-ts1--base.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumOB-tlf-ts1.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumOB-tosf-ly1--base.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumOB-tosf-ly1.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumOB-tosf-ot1--base.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumOB-tosf-ot1.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumOB-tosf-sc-ly1--base.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumOB-tosf-sc-ly1.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumOB-tosf-sc-ot1--base.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumOB-tosf-sc-ot1.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumOB-tosf-sc-t1--base.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumOB-tosf-sc-t1.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumOB-tosf-t1--base.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumOB-tosf-t1.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumOB-tosf-ts1--base.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumOB-tosf-ts1.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumOBO-lf-ly1--base.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumOBO-lf-ly1.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumOBO-lf-ot1--base.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumOBO-lf-ot1.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumOBO-lf-sc-ly1--base.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumOBO-lf-sc-ly1.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumOBO-lf-sc-ot1--base.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumOBO-lf-sc-ot1.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumOBO-lf-sc-t1--base.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumOBO-lf-sc-t1.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumOBO-lf-t1--base.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumOBO-lf-t1.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumOBO-lf-ts1--base.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumOBO-lf-ts1.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumOBO-osf-ly1--base.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumOBO-osf-ly1.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumOBO-osf-ot1--base.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumOBO-osf-ot1.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumOBO-osf-sc-ly1--base.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumOBO-osf-sc-ly1.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumOBO-osf-sc-ot1--base.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumOBO-osf-sc-ot1.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumOBO-osf-sc-t1--base.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumOBO-osf-sc-t1.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumOBO-osf-t1--base.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumOBO-osf-t1.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumOBO-osf-ts1--base.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumOBO-osf-ts1.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumOBO-tlf-ly1--base.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumOBO-tlf-ly1.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumOBO-tlf-ot1--base.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumOBO-tlf-ot1.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumOBO-tlf-sc-ly1--base.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumOBO-tlf-sc-ly1.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumOBO-tlf-sc-ot1--base.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumOBO-tlf-sc-ot1.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumOBO-tlf-sc-t1--base.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumOBO-tlf-sc-t1.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumOBO-tlf-t1--base.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumOBO-tlf-t1.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumOBO-tlf-ts1--base.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumTBO-lf-ot1--base.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumTBO-lf-ot1.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumTBO-lf-sc-ly1--base.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumTI-osf-sc-ot1--base.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumTI-osf-sc-ot1.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumTI-osf-sc-t1--base.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumTI-osf-sc-t1.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumTI-osf-t1--base.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumTI-osf-t1.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumTI-osf-ts1--base.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumTI-osf-ts1.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumTI-sup-ly1--base.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumTI-sup-ly1.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumTI-sup-ot1.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumTI-sup-t1--base.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumTI-sup-t1.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumTI-tlf-ly1--base.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/tfm/public/libertine/LinBiolinumTI-tlf-ly1.tfm
/usr/local/texlive/2020/tlpkg/tlpobj/libertine.tlpobj
/usr/local/texlive/2020/tlpkg/tlpobj/libertinegc.tlpobj
/usr/share/fonts/opentype/linux-libertine
/usr/share/fonts/opentype/linux-libertine/.uuid
```

And yet, `fc-list | grep -i libertine` doesn't produce anything at all.

How do I fix this? In the past, I was always able to fix LaTeX font problems with `sudo fc-cache -fv`, but not that's not doing the trick.

*EDIT: Some system info:*

**OS:**

Kubuntu 20.04

**Latex version:**

pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020)

kpathsea version 6.3.2

Copyright 2020 Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.

...

Compiled with libpng 1.6.37; using libpng 1.6.37

Compiled with zlib 1.2.11; using zlib 1.2.11

Compiled with xpdf version 4.02

**Install type:**

Vanilla TexLive 2020, as root.

**Compiler:**

XeLaTex

Comment: You seem to be running Linux, so you probably need to update your font configuration to index your TeX Live 2020 directory instead of the old path. [I wrote some instructions for Debian/Ubuntu here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/553305/61644).

Comment: If you’re running LuaTeX, you also want to run `sudo luaotfload-tool -f -u -p -v`.

Comment: @Davislor I'm running Kubuntu 20.04, yes. Installed TexLive as root, as I always have. I had purged all Ubuntu versions of Tex things years ago, pure vanilla TexLive since then. Using XeLaTeX. My paths are set as per your nice tutorial. My new install (TL2020) is in a separate directory from TL2018, so even if the paths haven't been updated, these fonts should be found.

Comment: Right, but you need to copy the configuration file to the right directory for `fc-cache` to know to search them. If you run it with -v`, does it list any of those directories in its search?

Comment: @Davislor I just followed your tutorial, and adding my TeX tree to the system font paths seems to have solved some of the problem. However, now I'm getting truly bizarre errors that I didn't used to get, in files that aren't even mine, e.g. in amssymb.sty I get "Command `\eth' already defined. ...ol{\eth} {\mathord}{AMSb}{"67}", as well as in my own files "Missing font identifier. ...s not specify its(microtype) \fontdimen 6 (". Plus a couple hundred errors about illegal units of measure and missing numbers and such. Could this solution have only partially fixed things?

Comment: @Davislor `fc-cache -v` returns three Libertine paths: /usr/share/fonts/opentype/linux-libertine, /usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/libertine, /usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/libertine. It also returns hundreds with errors, like "/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm: skipping, looped directory detected". This persists even after `sudo fc-cache -rv`

Comment: I would try the following: 1. Make sure that all TeX Live 2018 files are removed from your font path and configuration directory, 2. find your local caches with `ls -a ~` and clear them; they’ll have names like `.texlive2020`, 3. Make sure you're running the correct `fc-cache`, and 4. Run `fc-cache -r -s -v` and `sudo $(which updmap-sys)`.

Comment: Actually, probably simpler to just wipe TeX Live and do a clean reinstall. It sounds as if you're somehow mixing old and new TeX Live files.

Comment: If you check the `.log` file for the run that was giving you errors, is it looking up any files from a different version of TeX Live, or is it getting them all from the correct tree?

Comment: No references to TL2018 in the log file. I've tried `fc-cache -r -s -v` and `sudo $(which updmap-sys)`, but no joy. I'm going to try a fresh install again. This is too much of a mess. Thanks! Will report back.

Comment: Another thing `tlmgr` should take care of is `sudo $(which texhash)`, but it doesn’t sound as if the system’s got any old filenames cached there.

Comment: Amd ,ale sire you don't have any other copies installed, such as the `texlive-base` apt package.

Comment: I doubt that your follow up problem is an installation problem, better a small complete example, so that we can test if we get the error too.

Comment: Reinstalled from absolute scratch, as user, following tutorial above. Fonts detected as well as last time after I did the symlink, but a MASSIVE number of errors still occur. Will make a separate question. Thanks to all.